# Using grep in BBEdit

Tags: html, regex, bbedit

I'd like BBEdit to search some HTML and match every paragraph tag that contains a text string like "myText".

This sort of works but often matches beyond the closing ">" of the tag.

```
<p.*myText[^>]*>
```

As I understand it, this should match the opening angle bracket-"p", then any number of characters until it finds "myText", then any number of characters that are NOT ">" until it finds the closing ">". What's wrong?

Comment: Give us an example where this regex does not work.

Comment: Of course it will, use `<p\s[^>]*myText[^>]*>`

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Better yet, I think I understand why!

Answer (score 0):

Use `<p\s[^>]*myText[^>]*>` – from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951759/using-grep-in-bbedit/36309222#comment57636410_34951759) by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew).